# Как экранировать второй апостроф?

Tags: bash, echo

В конец файла wp-config.php нужно добавить строку

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );
```

Такая команда экранирует только один апостроф,

```
echo  $'define(\047'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );' >> wp-config.php
```

в результате выглядит вот так.

```
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT047, true );
```

Подскажите, как экранировать второй?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Комбинация `\047'` — это не экранирование кавычки, а она собственной персоной (ASCII код восьмиричной системе счисления) и окончание строкового литерала.

Следовательно, вам досточно лишь написать единый литерал, где в нужных местах будет `\047` для обозначения кавычки.

```
echo $'define(\047DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT\047, true);' >> wp-config.php
```

Однако более каноничными (и как мне кажется, более логичными) вариантами будут такие:

```
echo -e 'define(\047DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT\047, true);'
echo $'define(\'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT\', true);'
```

В первом варианте для интерпретации используется команда **echo** с параметром `-e`. Во втором случае, экранирование кавычки интерпретирует **bash** так же как это принято в других языка программирования.

Comment: или `echo "define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );"` ...